# Custom file names in "fs.writefile" function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to create a new file everytime a user runs a command, but I am having trouble finding out how to make the file name a custom one. Such as `"user1.json"`.

```
let user = {
    name: 'testname123',
    ID: 2,
    firstseen: '02/02/2019',
    cookies: '1'
};

let data = JSON.stringify(user, null, 2);

fs.writeFile('.json', data, (err) => {  
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Data written to file');
});
```

I tried to put `${user.name}` in the `fs.writeFile` function, but it just creates a file called `${user.name}` instead of taking the variable from the user array that I created earlier.

Comment: you are talking about ```fs.writeFile( `${user.name}`) ```;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not properly using template literals. If you use them in single or double quotes, they will not be replaced. You need to use backticks:

```
fs.writeFile(`${user.name}.json`, ...
```

Comment: Also known as template literals: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Thank you, I changed the answer accordingly.